# How can I click button or div tag dynamically until it disappear from page using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Using [this link](https://www.zomato.com/ncr/salad-days-dlf-cyber-city-gurgaon) I want all reviews from that page.
I have used xpaths(given in sample code) to click load more until it disappear from that page,but my solution fails and giving following errors.

**Error- Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM Stacktrace**

or

**in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''**

**Sample Code with xpaths**

```
Either 
driver.execute_script('$("div.load-more").click();')

or

xpath_content='//div[@class = "load-more"]' 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_content).click()
```

Is there any solution which may not fail in any case? How can I click on load more until it disappear form that page or Is there any other way to get all reviews from this page?

One more thing I am using firepath to generate review's xpath which is **.//*[@id='reviews-container']/div[1](https://www.zomato.com/ncr/salad-days-dlf-cyber-city-gurgaon)/div[3]/div[1](https://www.zomato.com/ncr/salad-days-dlf-cyber-city-gurgaon)/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1](https://www.zomato.com/ncr/salad-days-dlf-cyber-city-gurgaon)/div**
Is there a way to get our own xpath instead using firepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a java solution for your problem. You can use the same logic for python as well

```
public static void loadAll(WebDriver driver) {
    while (true) {
        //Using findElements to get list of elements so that it wont throw exception if element is not present
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='load-more']"));
        //If the size is zero that means load more element is not present so breaking the loop
        if (elements.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        //Assigning first element to a variable 
        WebElement loadEl = elements.get(0);
        //Getting text of element
        String text = loadEl.getText().toLowerCase();
         //check if text contains load more, as, if it is loading it will have ... ,so we cant click at that time
        if (text.contains("load more")) {
            loadEl.click();
        }
        //if text contains 1 to 4 means [for ex "Load More 4"] this is the last click so breaking the loop
        if (text.matches("load more [1-4]")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have developed your logic in python but If  I use it for multiple links it throws exception -**in _read_status raise BadStatusLine(line) httplib.BadStatusLine: ''** or sometime **Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class=\"load-more\"]"}**. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: you might not have noticed my last question, how to write own  review's xpath for   **.//*[@id='reviews-container']/div1/div[3]/div1/div/div/div[3]/div/div1/div** ?

Comment: @Mukesh I couldn't get you. *you might not have noticed my last question*,whats the question and wher's the link to it?

Comment: I was asking about  the last line of my Question, to write own xpath of review.For now I have solved it. I still get exceptions(above in first comment) while clicking on **load more** for multiple links? How to solve it?